# add transitions to a hide/show javascript dom

Tags: javascript, transition

I have this function (and 3 more like it)

```
function property (){
 document.getElementById("property").style.display = "block";
 document.getElementById("hotel").style.display = "none";
 document.getElementById("other").style.display = "none";
 document.getElementById("main").style.display = "none";
 }
```

How can I add a transition to the change of divs. The function is called on links.

Now it just shows the div that is clicked, and hides the others. But I would like the old div to fade out and the new to fade in..

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

a popular way is to use jQuery:

```
$('#property').fadeIn();
```

and that's it.  The page http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/ has some demo.

Answer (score 0):

**Usage ([Demo](http://jsbin.com/aduta4/))**

```
fadeIn(element, 200); // ms
fadeIn("#element_id", 300);
fadeOut(element, 600, function() {
  alert("fade finished");
});
```

**Code**

```
function fade(dom, current, target, duration, after) {
  duration = duration || 600;
  if (typeof dom === "string")
    dom = document.getElementById(dom);
  var start = +new Date();
  var finish = start + duration;
  var easing = function (pos) {
    return (-Math.cos(pos * Math.PI) / 2) + 0.5;
  };
  var interval = setInterval(function () {
    var now = +new Date();
    var pos = now > finish ? 1 : (now - start) / duration;
    setOpacity(dom, interpolate(current, target, easing(pos)));
    if (now > finish) {
      clearInterval(interval);
      after && after();
    }
  }, 13);
}

function fadeIn(dom, duration, after) {
  fade(dom, 0, 1, duration, after);
}
function fadeOut(dom, duration, after) {
  fade(dom, 1, 0, duration, after);
}

function setOpacity(obj, value) {
  if (obj) {
    obj.style.opacity = value;
    obj.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=' + value * 100 + ')';
    obj.style.zoom = 1;
  }
}
function interpolate(source, target, pos) {
  return (source + (target - source) * pos).toFixed(3);
}​
```

Comment: Thanks. its working. But, before the new div is shown you see the background.. Is is possible to avoid that. maybe having the old div fade out a little later. maybe the fade in starts to late.. Where to change that??

Comment: ohh and one of my divs contains a swf. it dos not seem to work on that..?

Comment: I don't fully understand what your problem is. If you want the transition to be happening between two states you need to start a `fadeIn` and a `fadeOut` at the same time. Also if you want the divs to overlap you need a container with `position:relaitve` and the divs to be `position:absolute`. In this way the transition happens between overlapping divs, fading from one to another. Post an example on http://jsbin.com if you need more help.

Comment: As for the swf: use `wmode="transparent"`.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/upoqi4/edit.

What I would like to avoid is the millisecond (or whatever) between the 2 divs..

Comment: But I dont know if it is possible, since the div is only visible one at a time...

Comment: You need the `container` and the css `position` s that I've talked about. Here is a fully commented **demo**: http://jsbin.com/upoqi4/6/edit . Good luck!

Comment: It **does** work. Use `wmode="opaque"` on the flash in order to get transparency - http://jsbin.com/upoqi4/8